# How can I use native TextField components?

Tags: flutter

Today I understand that Flutter TextField widget hasn't implement native for Android and iOS editing mechanic (here I mean cursor movement, selecting, etc.), and form [GitHub issues count](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20TextField) for these topics I understand that to get there it must pass a long way.

Maybe someone could suggest me how I can use corresponding native component of Android ([android.widget.EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)) and iOS ([UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/)). Some already existed package or maybe technic?

Comment: For example in Google Ads (app from Flutter showcase page) for "Search for campaigns" input Flutter TextField widget used but for "Send Feedback" input native widget used.

Comment: Flutter uses material design to handle [TextFields](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) if you want to use the native text field components you need to write [custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: I think that I found the answer to my question - it is PlatformViews. Just read the [Build your Own Plugin using (PlatformViews)](https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/build-your-own-plugin-using-platformviews-flutter-5b42b4c4fb0a) and PlatformViews looks promising. But I have not checked this technique with TextField components yet. That is why left my question opened until.